# How to make karma coverage work with Angular 14 + webpack 5?

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-coverage

here is an example of my files structure : https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-ng14-wp5

you can run `npm run test` and see the test is well executed but the coverage does not work.

how to do it ?
[image]